# Symfony - Building query for table created by many to many relation

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have 2 entities connected with many to many relation into a 3th table, and I want to get every color for an id of product:

```
/**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Color", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="products_colors",
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="color_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *     )
     */
    private $colors;
```

And in my second entity:

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Product", mappedBy="colors")
 */
private $products;
```

This is my query: (I was trying to make some joins but cant make it work)

```
class ProductRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    public function getColors($id)
    {
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->join('AppBundle\Entity\Color', 'c')
            ->where('c.product_id = :id')
            ->setParameter('id', $id)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();

        return $query;
    }
}
```

I got this error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 85 near 'product_id =': Error: Class
>   AppBundle\Entity\Color has no field or association named product_id

which I understand, but can't think of a way to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony expects you to reference the entity (not id) of an object when mapped by ManyToMany relationship. Try:

```
class ProductRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    public function getColors(Product $product)
    {
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->join('AppBundle\Entity\Color', 'c')
            ->where('c.product = :product')
            ->setParameter('product', $product)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();

        return $query;
    }
}
```

Of course you'll have to modify your call to this function accordingly.

You can also skip the query creation altogether with the getter function in your entity; symfony automagically will do the query for you.

```
// class Product

private $colors; // as you have it set up already

/**
 * @return ArrayCollection|Color[]
 */

public function getColors()
{
    return $this->colors;
}
```

Comment: Omg, im so dumb, I have done this, I made it before and have the getColors function, but instead of using it, im trying to build some black magic :O thanks anyway